Why does California allow potential illegal immigrants to get a driver's license?
On the California DMV page,
it says:

AB 60 driver’s licenses are for individuals who are unable to provide proof of legal presence in the United States, but who meet California DMV requirements and are able to provide proof of identity and California residency.

Source: https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/driver-licenses-identification-cards/assembly-bill-ab-60-driver-licenses/
Anyone who is unable to provide proof of legal presence in the US is a potential illegal immigrant. In a country with significant negative feelings toward immigrants, why is this permitted? What is the incentive?

That seems to be a pretty bold statement to state that being unable to get the needed documents makes you a potential illegal immigrant. Those kind of documents can get lost over the years and can be hard to replace even if you are born in the country to parents who were also born in the county.

Why would they require someone to prove citizenship? A driver's license doesn't assert citizenship, merely identity, state of residence, and whether or not you can drive.

@Cadence A driver's license is the de-facto national ID for many places, so its relevance is not limited to just someone's right to drive.  Besides the question did not cite proof of citizenship.  Lots of comments, claiming "obvious reasons".  Few answers.  Seems worth hearing about the reasons as I am 200% sure Trump has at some point whined about this.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: "it would also be nice to check if other US states do the same or if California is an exception" The table here lists the states and territories which currently issue driver's licenses which do not require legal presence documents.

In the U.S. federal system, states are not part of the immigration system.

@Cadence because ideally states shouldn’t make life easier for those who are in the country illegally?..

What proof of legal presence do you think they should require? This seems to be assuming that all legal residents have a card saying they're allowed to be in the USA, and if that's true you should prove it.

California is an agricultural state, and agricultural states (as a rule) heavily rely on migrant workers. Many of these migrant workers are in the country illegally, sometimes seasonally, sometimes long-term. Migrant workers also work in a large number of low-skill jobs: service industries, landscaping, maintenance, housekeeping, etc.
These people will drive, whether they have licenses or not, because they have to drive to get around in California. It's to the state's (and citizens') advantage for them to be licensed, registered, and insured like every other driver, even if they're here illegally.

These people will drive, whether they have licenses or not => if California wanted they could crack down on that. They just choose not to.

@JonathanReez: California (like may states) needs low-wage workers in a lot of fields. Crack down on illegal immigrants and the nuts/fruits/tubers don't make it to the market, much less gardening, service and janitorial work, uber drivers, etc... Don't cut off your nose to spite your face, as the saying goes.

Right but I’m specifically critiquing the second part of your answer. It should say: “California chooses to let them drive, so they also issues them a license”.

@JonathanReez: That's just common sense. It isn't that CA chooses to let them drive; CA acknowledges that they are going to drive. There's not a damned thing CA can do to stop them. So if they are going to drive, they should be licensed.

I don't often think that Ted's answers are valid, because he seldom backs them up with sources, but in this case, I strongly do. Jonathan, I think you are being unreasonably obtuse here. This is it in a nutshell. If there is a need for migrant workers, citizens or not, and they will drive, then ensure they are insured and licensed..

@JonathanReez There are "crack downs" on drunk driving all the time, all over the US.  There are "crack downs" on gun crime.  And decades of "crack downs" on drug abuse.  None of them ever seem to work.  Migrant farm workers of, shall we say, "dubious immigration status" have been a necessary fixture of California (and Texas!) agriculture for more than a century.  Probably even centuries given the history of the area, although prior to the mid-1800s it was all Mexico.  And I suspect there was no effective border until the mid 20th century or so.  This answer is spot-on IMO.

@TedWrigley On the other hand, governments still forbid rape and murder; they don't just say, "Well, it's going to happen anyway, there is nothing we can do." That's not to say that illegal immigrants driving is on par with those crimes (it isn't), just that acknowledging that something will happen does not necessitate legally allowing it.

@InHocSigno that analogy is inapt because the point of licensing drivers is to ensure that people driving motor vehicles are competent -- adequately trained to operate them relatively safely.  The goal of laws forbidding driving without a license, therefore, is also to ensure that people driving motor vehicles are competent.  On the other hand, the point of forbidding rape and murder is to prevent rape and murder.

@InHocSigno: I wish people understood law better. Laws never prevent crime. Laws define what 'crimes' are; laws punish people after they commit crimes. Punishments may deter people from committing crimes, but every law tacitly accepts that crimes will be committed. This is as true for rape and murder as it is for driving without a license. CA merely has the common sense to solve the problem (allowing unlawful immigrants to get licenses, so they can drive legally), not compound the problem (by making unlawful immigrants break traffic laws as well).

The holder of an AB60 license could be an illegal immigrant or a legal immigrant (or less likely a citizen) who did not want to provide all necessary documentaton.

The stated purpose of the Safe and Responsible Driver’s Act was to ensure that motorists are passing all license requirements other than immigration status to increase road safety. (Talking points from an advocacy group, another advocacy group.)
A regular license for legal immigrants would expire with the end of their legal status, which adds a complication for all those who receive multiple extensions. (DMV)
DHS gets access to some DMV records, but not the information if the license was issued with or without residency check. So obviously the act is designed to encourage illegal immigrants or those with unclear status to get a license. (Advocacy group)
Checking the residency status of "potential illegal immigrants" requires checking the residency status of everyone, including "obvious citizens," unless the decision to ask for proof is based on accent or skin color.
For historical reasons, the United States refuse to issue easy citizenship proof like a compulsory national ID card with the related database to track all citizens. Since the US clearly feel a need for a national id, the introduced REAL ID without making it compulsory.


One can argue that the Federal government did its best to make it compulsory (within the confines of the US constitution), by preventing anyone w/o one from flying on a plane in the US. Which is probably as far it could go under the Commerce Clause. (That is if we leave aside the Obama era reluctance to enforce REAL ID.)

@264champagnebottlesonice, this "within the confines" is the key. The US Constitution was groundbreaking two and a half centuries ago, but they never got into the habit of updating it when circumstances change. Hence the interstate clause was twisted into a pretzel ...

What about providing some links to at least the Act or its wiki entry?

@ItalianPhilosopher, the OP provided a link to the DMV. Isn't that enough?

I guess it doesn't matter.  The top answer spins up a nice sounding hypothesis but provides no sources or hard info, yet is miles ahead.  I thought maybe more sourcing would help.  Oh well.

@ItalianPhilosopher, since we're on Politics rather than Law, I added links to people arguing my explanation, not to the act itself. Except for the last two points, which are an outsider's perspective on US foibles.

@264champagnebottlesonice there are other forms of ID that can be used to board a plane, including a foreign passport, and it's also possible to board a plane with "unacceptable" ID by submitting to an extended screening process.

From CA DMV

The federal REAL ID Act places new rules on which forms of identification may be used to board flights within the United States (U.S.) and enter secure federal facilities, such as military bases, federal courthouses, and other federal facilities.  A California issued REAL ID driver’s license or identification card meets these new requirements and is marked with a golden bear and star.
Applying for a REAL ID requires proof of identity, proof of California residency, and a trip to DMV. You will be asked to provide your Social Security number on your REAL ID application (exceptions may apply).
Individuals applying for or renewing an AB 60 driver’s license are not eligible to receive a REAL ID driver’s license or identification card.

So, the diff is that some DLs are REAL ID compliant and some not.
What's needed to needed to meet REAL ID law requirements? For instance

Unexpired Permanent Resident Card

But one may still extend an expired one. UCSIS even changes the deadline for that at their discretion apparently, e.g. they moved it from 24 to 36 months recently. (Apparently one is issued an "ADIT stamp" in that situation, i.e. after applying for an extension to an expired green card within the UCSIS 'grace period', but that doesn't seem to count towards REAL ID.)
And apparently, despite the REAL ID act being of 2005 vintage, California didn't start to apply it until 2019, if I'm reading Wikipedia's "States and territories by year of DHS certification as Real ID compliant" correctly on this.
In fact the CA situation was hardly unique:

Most states and territories decided to offer two versions of identification documents, one compliant with the Real ID requirements and one not compliant. [...]
Many state legislatures strongly opposed the Real ID Act, before the states eventually complied with it years later.

There is much more on that in this paper cited as ref on Wikipedia. Since it was a Bush law, it was indeed opposed most staunchly by Democrats, but also e.g.

Governor Mike Huckabee (R-AR) opposed what he called the Bush administration’s encroachment on states’ rights. [...]
In August 2017, Missouri became the last state to commit to REAL ID compliance, after Governor Eric Greitens (R) signed HB 151 into law (Keeping IDentities Safe 2017a).

(The Missouri governor was a Democrat 2009-2017.)
During the Obama administration the DHS Secretary often talked about repealing the REAL ID act, but they never had the votes for it. Only the Trump administration apparently started to enforce it seriously.

Another interviewee put it this way: “The problem came when Secretary Napolitano came over. She made [multiple] comments opposing REAL ID as Secretary of Homeland Security. Her mike is a lot bigger than that of a REAL ID Office of five guys. So many states made the strategic decision to not comply with REAL ID (…) Napolitano went on a warpath on REAL ID. Unusual.”


Thanks to a comment below, I found out that Wisconsin is among the states where the non-REAL-ID is almost as strict in its requirements for documenting legal presence as the real REAL ID DL. Unsurprisingly, Wisconsin was also certified among the first wave for REAL ID compliance. And also they get some flak from pro-immigration groups, along the lines of

Wisconsin’s Dairy Industry Relies on Undocumented Immigrants, but the State Won’t Let Them Legally Drive.
Law enforcement officials say the roads are less safe because undocumented immigrants aren’t trained and tested on basic driving rules but they drive anyway — and often without insurance. Court officials say tickets for driving without a license overwhelm their dockets and drain their limited resources. Farmers say they have to build or find employee housing to help their workers avoid getting ticketed. [...]
“You can’t call Uber because there isn’t any. You can’t take the bus because there aren’t any,” said John Rosenow, a dairy farmer in western Wisconsin who has become one of the most prominent advocates for immigrant workers in the state.  [...]
Advocates for immigrants have worked for years to persuade lawmakers to give undocumented immigrants driving privileges, as 19 states — most of them blue — have done. But those efforts have been unsuccessful in Wisconsin, where legislative districts have been drawn to favor Republicans. Few GOP lawmakers have been willing to support any such efforts; political observers say the lawmakers don’t want to look soft on immigration.
[...] In one county, officials have been quietly conducting a pilot driver’s education program aimed largely at undocumented immigrants who were caught driving without a license. They are reluctant to speak publicly about it out of fear that any attention will lead to conservative backlash.
Elected district attorneys in several counties have stopped bringing criminal charges against people caught driving without a license; both Democrat and Republican prosecutors say they want to dedicate their limited resources to crimes with victims.
And in four counties in southwestern Wisconsin, community advocates worked with local law enforcement agencies and dairy farmers a few years ago to create identification cards that workers could show officers during traffic stops to prove that they worked in the area and, potentially, keep those encounters from escalating.
“It did not prevent them from getting a ticket, but it prevented them from being handcuffed and hauled off to jail,” said Shirley Barnes, the recently retired co-director of the MultiCultural Outreach Program in Dodgeville.

OTOH, from the rest of that piece, it seem to be a real money making machine for the state, with somewhere in between 50% and 75% of driving infraction tickets (depending on location urban vs rural) given to the ~8% Hispanic/illegal population.
Also, from the piece, there's now a (black) market in WI for registering cars under someone else's (i.e. a citizen's) name, since cops usually just run the license plates before pulling someone over.
So if CA (and those 19 states) is (& are) more lax, I guess they'd claim they want to avoid issues like those.

This answer is very technical and revolves about something called "REAL ID". Maybe a summary in simpler terms can be added and the used term explained a bit more. What is a REAL ID?

This answer doesn't address the question. The question is about driver's licenses that do not require legal presence documents, not about REAL ID or non-REAL-ID driver's licenses. Non-REAL-ID does mean it doesn't require legal presence documents. Only 21 states or territories issue driver's licenses that do not require legal presence documents. Many states issue non-REAL-ID documents that require legal presence documents. Even California issues non-REAL-ID documents that require legal presence documents.

@user102008 "Many states issue non-REAL-ID documents that require legal presence documents." Such as?

@264champagnebottlesonice: Here are a few:AK, AZ, CA, MO, NH, OH, WI

@user102008: it's not particularly convincing. For example, you linked a CA doc from 2018, while they were apparently in the process of getting the REAL ID certification, which they got in 2019, according to Wikipedia.

@user102008: OTOH for WI, they allow (only) a slightly broader range of documents for the non-REAL-ID DL. So, point conceded there, there's little diff in WI. Unsurprisingly, WI was certified in the first wave in 2012, so they really dig REAL ID.

@user102008: mostly aside, but WI is getting some flak from pro-immigration groups due to those strict requirements even for the non-REAL-ID DLs https://www.propublica.org/article/wisconsin-dairy-undocumented-immigrants-drivers-licenses "Wisconsin’s Dairy Industry Relies on Undocumented Immigrants, but the State Won’t Let Them Legally Drive"

All the emphasis on REAL-ID makes this answer significantly off point. The question is about driver's licenses in general, not REAL-ID.

The table - https://www.nilc.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/drivers-license-access-table-06-2024pdf-1.pdf - linked to in a comment, listing 20 other states often refers to REAL ID, so there is a link there.  What's less certain is which came first - the alternative driver license, for other reasons.  Or Real ID which then brought in the alternative license.

A big problem with the Real ID requirements is that most states have interpreted them to require documents that are not necessary to establish lawful presence, notably the requirement to have a valid visa.  Most Canadian residents of the US won't have any visa, and citizens of other countries may have visas that have expired, which is perfectly fine under US immigration law and does not render their presence unlawful.

@phoog: "most states have interpreted them to require documents that are not necessary to establish lawful presence, notably the requirement to have a valid visa" It's not up to the state. Federal regulations require valid visa for establishing identity (not for lawful status) when the foreign-passport-and-I-94 option is used. See 6 CFR 37.11(c)(1)(vi).

@264champagnebottlesonice: "it's not particularly convincing. For example, you linked a CA doc from 2018" CA started issuing REAL ID driver's licenses in 2018. They haven't had to update the documents checklist for federal non-compliant driver's licenses since then. It is linked to from multiple pages, e.g. https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/driver-licenses-identification-cards/instruction-permits/ "Bring your California Identification Card or proof of identity and residency. (Federal Noncompliant/REAL ID/AB60)"

@user102008 be that as it may, DC, at least, does not seem to ask for a valid visa, only the I-94 and, for some statuses, a supporting document such as a DS-1019 or I-20: https://dmv.dc.gov/page/real-id-proof-lawful-presence -- perhaps there are a lot of Canadians in DC.

@phoog: But on the proof of identity page, it does list "Unexpired Foreign Passport with accompanying Visa"

@user102008 I see, thanks.  Do you know whether anyone has tried to bring to the attention of the DHS or of Congress that the statutory and regulatory scheme has excluded two classes of lawfully president nonimmigrants from obtaining Real ID?

@phoog: These were brought up by comments to the regulation, e.g. https://www.federalregister.gov/d/08-140/p-325 , https://www.federalregister.gov/d/08-140/p-347 , https://www.federalregister.gov/d/08-140/p-604 . DHS basically said: expired visa cannot establish identity because it is expired, foreign passport cannot be used because the statute requires the document to be verified with the issuing agency, and there is no guarantee they can do that with a foreign government. I don't think Congress cares enough about an edge-case for non-citizens to fix it.

@phoog: REAL ID is generally not essential for non-citizens anyway, since a foreign passport, green card, or EAD are acceptable for TSA (and aliens are required by law to carry passport with entry stamp, I-94, EAD, or green card  anyway). Some states already impose more restrictions than the federal regulations, e.g. CO does not issue REAL ID docs to foreigners without a green card, and WA does not issue REAL ID docs to non-citizens at all (even those with a green card). So tweaking the rules for a small subset of non-citizens is not a high priority.

@user102008 "Aliens are required by law to carry passport with entry stamp, I-94, EAD, or green card anyway": but surely you realize that in practice virtually no nonimmigrant who resides in the US actually does, and anybody who is aware of the requirement would most likely fulfill it by carrying a printout of the I-94 from the website, which is entirely useless for the TSA.  Furthermore, Nebraska, Texas, and Wyoming do not issue non-Real-ID licenses.  What is a Canadian resident of one of those states, for example in TN status, supposed to do?  I guess they're driving illegally.
